# Script to get View Fields for a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, csom

I have a Site collection with 50 Lists and Libraries . Is there any powershell script that iterates through all lists and get its content type , Views,View Properties  in a CSV file.

I tried like this but the order in my csv is not proper.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 

#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/PGDCA"
$UserName="ssdasasdsa@gh.vom"
$Password ="123456"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
$ct = @();
$systemlibs = @("Data Connections Test","Images","Pages","Site Assets", "Site Collection Documents","Site Collection Images", "Site Pages", "Style Library","Tasks","test","Test Library","TestForm","Workflow Tasks")
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials

try 
{
    #Set up the context

    #Get All Lists
    $Lists = $Context.web.Lists
    $Context.Load($Lists)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Iterate through each list in a site  
    forEach($List in $Lists)
    {
        if($List.Hidden -eq $false)
        {
            if(-not ($systemlibs -Contains $List.Title))
            {
                #Write-Host $List.Title
                $ListTitle = $List.Title
                GetSPListView $Context $ListTitle
            } 
        }
    }
}
catch 
{
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}


function GetSPListView ($Context, $ListName)
{
    #Write-Host "This is My"$ListName

    $spList = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName);
    $Context.load($spList)
    $Context.load($spList.Views)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach($Listview in $spList.Views)
    {
        $Context.Load($Listview)
        $Context.Load($Listview.ViewFields)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        if($Listview.Hidden-eq $false)
        {
            Write-Host $ListName ":" $Listview.Title ":" $Listview.ViewFields 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. You are mixing CTs and Views in one bowl - as they are not related, You should collect information separately. One run looking for content types, other for views.

Comment: I was able to get all the views along with the fields. However i was unable to store all of  them in CSV file. but i was bale to do it in Write-host  I have updated my code in the orginal.